# Mongoexport giving authentication failed error

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongoexport

I am trying to export MongoDB collection.
**MongoDB version: 3.0.15 Community**

I have tried:

```
mongoexport --uri "mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>?authsource=admin" --collection <collection_name> --out D:/mongo_export/demo.json
```

This is giving me authentication error as follow:

```
error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
```

But if I try to go in shell using:

```
mongo mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>?authsource=admin
```

I am able to go to mongo shell. This means, `--uri` is correct for `mongoexport` command.

Then why am I getting error for `mongoexport`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per mongo document for version 3.0, I have tried:

```
mongoexport -h <host:port>-u <username>-p <password>-d <db name>-c <collection name> -o D:/mongo_export/demo.json
```